# PDF transformation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

I need help with part (a)

So far I've done

Fy(y)=P(Y<=y)

=P(X^3/theta<=y)

=P(X<=(ytheta)^1/3)

And I'm not sure where to go from there. I'm also not too sure what to do for the other parts of the question, so if someone could help me out with those that would be great

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions when possible, rather than posting links.  Links can't be browsed and may not be accessible to those using screen readers.  For help on typesetting math on this site, see this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

You have:

$$\begin{align}
F_Y(y)&=\Bbb P(Y\leq y)
\\&=\Bbb P(X^3/\Theta\leq y)
\\&=\Bbb P(X\leq (y\Theta)^{1/3})
\\&=F_X((y\Theta)^{1/3})
\end{align}$$

That is correct.

Next, recall that the probability density function is the unsigned derivative of the cumulative distribution function.

$$\begin{align}
f_Y(y)&=\left\lvert\dfrac{\mathrm d ~F_X((y\Theta)^{1/3})}{\mathrm d ~y\qquad\qquad~~~}\right\rvert
\\[2ex] &=\left\lvert\dfrac{\mathrm d~(y\Theta)^{1/3}}{\mathrm d~ y\qquad~~}\right\rvert f_X((y\Theta)^{1/3})
\end{align}$$

Now carry on from here.

Comment: So you replace x in fx(x) with (ytheta)^1/3 but i'm not sure how to do the derivative part. can you please help?

Comment: @Spartasporter It is of the form $\dfrac{\mathrm d~a y^n}{\mathrm d~y~~~}= any^{n-1}$.

Comment: Is it theta^-2/3 * y^-1/3 * -(e^-y/2) / 2?. I'm pretty dumb so I don't know what to do from there.